# Is binary tree that is just None can be considered a min-heap tree?

Tags: python, binary-tree, min-heap

I need to write a recursion for a min-heap binary tree to check if this tree is min-heap. One of the test cases is just NONE.

Is `None` considered a min-heap tree and returns `True`, or `None` is `False`?

The reason I am asking is that I will reach leaves at some point and their nodes are `None` and if base case is `True` then it will return `True`.

Comment: That depends. Does your implementation use `None` to represent an empty tree?

Comment: What on earth is a mean-heap?

Comment: I think he means min-heap

Comment: yep, my bad: min-heap, and yes, my tree has None to represent an empty tree

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a none type will be vacuously true as it does not violate the definition of a min-heap tree.

Comment: I saw somewhere in wikipedia that it is sort of considered True, but can't convince myself and I am uncertain. Thank you. I will create my function under assumption that just: tree = None will return True.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, None is considered a mean-heap tree.

Answer (score 0):

You must mean a Min Heap. When we are dealing with any tree structure the children of a Node are most commonly initialized as None. **One** of the reasons is that we can easily escape the recursion as such:

```
def find_node(node, data):
   if root is None:
      return
   if root.data == data:
       print "Node found"
   find_node(node.left, data)
   find_node(node.right, data)



class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
       self.left = None
       self.right = None
       self.data = data
```

In your case you want to check if a tree is min heap by traversing it. You would do something like that

```
def is_min_heap(root):
  #.....check here and then do
  return is_min_heap(root.left) and is_min_heap(root.right)
```

But it depends how you want to handle it. Any one node with no children is a min-heap or a max-heap but it has no meaning. If you want to call

`is_min_heap(None)` then you are free to do so but it is up to you if you want to say that is True or not.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented a function and it works correctly. I was just confused with understanding of a binary tree if I should consider None a tree or not.
Once, I knew the answer (I considered a None a True case) recursion was sort of the easiest part to implement. Thank you.